# how the members can login to civicrm

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember, user-account

after I created the signup and renewal page and configuring it, I found that it is not accessible by people who are not wordpress users, how to solve this, and how the users can enter their profiles without being users in wordpress(in another word to be a user in civicrm and not user in wordpress)?

Comment: Could you please ask your question more clearly?  Are you asking how to allow visitors without accounts to fill in a CiviCRM profile?  Or are you asking how to allow visitors without WordPress accounts to log in?  If the second option, what precisely do you want them to log in to?

Answer (score 1):

Muhamed - you can allow people to register anonymously, they do not have to be 'members' or users in WP. When people register, their name, email and address information will be used to create new 'contact' records. It is a matter of setting up CiviCRM permissions as you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should install a plugin to grant permission for the user

Please refer to the below plugin 
https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-wordpress-member-sync

I guess this helps !!!