# Can a CiviCRM member upload post content to a cutstom post type in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, user

In short, can a person register on CiviCRM, and then be given permission to post content for review (such as an upcoming event or job opportunity), which can then be moderated and approved by an admin?

We are considering CiviCRM for our organisation and think this is possible, but want to make sure.

Comment: You will need to give a little more detail about your requirement for us to be able to help you. For example, a person does not register on CiviCRM? CiviCRM stores contacts? A little more explanation will provide you with better and more helpful answers.

Comment: The user will register on the front-end of the website (which I presume will be a CiviCRM form?), and then gets added as a user/member in the CRM & Wordpress. From the link in the comment below it looks like Wordpress handles and stores this information (username & password), and syncs with a contact on CiviCRM. The user will then need to access members-only content, make payments, request help via a form, and post articles, job opportunities and upcoming events which will need to be approved by an administrator. Does that help?

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with CiviCRM so was not sure exactly what to ask, but thanks for clarifying! I went for the simplest explanation I could, but feel like I'm starting to understand the system a bit better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Users are managed by WordPress and you can give specific roles permissions to access components in CiviCRM. Content management is handled by WordPress. I am not sure of all the details but it sound like you will need to manage permissions in both CiviCRM & WordPress for specific roles.

Take a look at this post. It has info on a similar scenario with some info on plugins that might help.
[Including Member Login to a CiviCRM Site](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17216/including-member-login-to-a-civicrm-site/17222#17222)

Hope this helps...

Comment: That does help KilakwaBT, thanks! It looks like that covers most of what we are wanting to do, but am just wondering if Wordpress is the most stable way to go about this? I am comfortable with Wordpress, and so would like to stick with it but the functionality we are looking for seems to be a bit of a mission to implement - have you had success with this kind of setup before?

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline how this can be done (with no additional code) with Drupal. Someone with more Wordpress knowledge can translate - or identify the gaps in the Wordpress integration:

The Drupal way:

- send a user to a CiviCRM profile page -> the user fills it out; is added to a CiviCRM group and a Drupal account is created in the process;
- Using CiviCRM group-role sync the Drupal account has a specific role; user can log in and add content of eg type submit conference paper (or job post) content is unpublished
- Conference organizers have permissions to view/approve i.e. publish content of type conference paper and permissions to fill out fields for day/time slot
- Drupal Views pulls these abstracts/author/date/timeslots together into various displays for conference programs and full conference proceedings

Comment: Thanks, KarinG. That sounds nice and straightforward! I am completely unfamiliar with Drupal but know Wordpress pretty well. The 2 main objectives of this project would be the CRM integration and a complete website refresh aligning with the new direction we're going in. I would be doing the front-end dev and design for the site and was hoping for an easy way to integrate the above functionality into it as easy as possible. I may have to consider digging into Drupal now - are you quite familiar with it?

Comment: Hi Mike - yes - we actually only develop/host Drupal/CiviCRM websites - because of all the workflow/integration options [at some point everyone always wants it to do more] - and in addition to the above there is webform_civicrm Drupal module and Drupal Views integration [both very powerful]. Then there is CiviCRM Entity as well - which is also very powerful.